# stylegan3 stylegan2-ada tensor mismatch error for every 256 or 512 flickr related model

Tags: python, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

Anyone having the same tensor size mismatch when trying finetuning on ffhq,ffhqu or celebahq models with stylegan3 (and with --cfg=stylegan2)?

With afhqv2  and metfaces I had no problems at 512 and 1048 sizes.

Error:

```
...
File "/home/ubuntu/stylegan3/training/training_loop.py", line 162, in training_loop
    misc.copy_params_and_buffers(resume_data[name], module, require_all=False)
  File "/home/ubuntu/stylegan3/torch_utils/misc.py", line 162, in copy_params_and_buffers
    tensor.copy_(src_tensors[name].detach()).requires_grad_(tensor.requires_grad)

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (512) must match the size of tensor b (256) at non-singleton dimension 0
```

example command:

```
python "train.py" --outdir=training-runs --cfg=stylegan3-r --data="datasets/256.zip" --gpus=1 --batch=16 --batch-gpu=16 --gamma=6.6 --mirror=1 --kimg=2 --snap=5  --resume=https://api.ngc.nvidia.com/v2/models/nvidia/research/stylegan3/versions/1/files/stylegan3-r-ffhqu-256x256.pkl
```

I've verified I was passing 256 images built with the tool:

```
python dataset_tool.py --source="img/" --dest="datasets/256.zip" --resolution='256x256'
```

Note: I was able to finetune only with this version stylegan2-ffhq-512x512.pkl

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to do transfer learning on "stylegan3-r-ffhqu-256x256.pkl", you should add

```
--cbase=16384
```

in your `python "train.py" ...` 
command line